# Shadows masks to bounds only on the left and upper side. What causes this?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, core-graphics, calayer

I'm trying to achieve a feature that allows adding a shadow to a transparent button. For this, I'm creating a layer that masks the shadows inside the view. However, my shadows are clipped on the left and upper sides but not clipped on the right and lower sides.

Here is how it looks (This is not a transparent button but they're also working fine except the shadow being clipped like this.):

[image]

And here is my code for achieving this:

```
private func applyShadow() {
    layer.masksToBounds = false

    if shouldApplyShadow && shadowLayer == nil {
        shadowLayer = CAShapeLayer()

        let shapePath = CGPath(roundedRect: bounds, cornerWidth: cornerRadi, cornerHeight: cornerRadi, transform: nil)

        shadowLayer.path = shapePath
        shadowLayer.fillColor = backgroundColor?.cgColor
        shadowLayer.shadowPath = shadowLayer.path
        shadowLayer.shadowRadius = shadowRadius ?? 8
        shadowLayer.shadowColor = (shadowColor ?? .black).cgColor
        shadowLayer.shadowOffset = shadowOffset ?? CGSize(width: 0, height: 0)
        shadowLayer.shadowOpacity = shadowOpacity ?? 0.8

        layer.insertSublayer(shadowLayer!, at: 0)

        /// If there's background color, there is no need to mask inner shadows.
        if backgroundColor != .none && !(innerShadows ?? false) {
            let maskLayer = CAShapeLayer()
            maskLayer.path = { () -> UIBezierPath in
                let path = UIBezierPath()
                path.append(UIBezierPath(cgPath: shapePath))
                path.append(UIBezierPath(rect: UIScreen.main.bounds))
                path.usesEvenOddFillRule = true
                return path
            }().cgPath

            maskLayer.fillRule = .evenOdd
            shadowLayer.mask = maskLayer
        }
    }
}
```

I think that's something related to the Even-Odd Fill Rule algorithm, I'm not sure. But how can I overcome this clipping problem?

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:** 
This is what a transparent button with borders and text on it looks when shadow applied.. Which I don't want.

[image]

What it should look like this. No shadows inside but also a clear background color. (Except the clipped top and left sides):

[image]

Comment: why don't you add the shadow directly to button layer instead of adding a sublayer.

Comment: There are various ways to add a shadow... can you show how you want it to look with a transparent button (using your "innerShadows"?

Comment: Thanks for the replies. I updated my question. @kjoe The first pic demonstrates what happens when you directly add shadow to your transparent layer.

Comment: @DonMag Latter picture is what I kind of trying to achieve, as I said before the only problem is clipping on the top and left sides. It's not that visible on this example though. But it's visible on the red button above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think a couple issues...

1. You are appending `UIBezierPath(rect: UIScreen.main.bounds)` to your path, but that puts the top-left corner at the top-left corner of the layer... which "clips" the top-left shadow.
2. If you **DO** have a background color, you'll need to clip those corners as well, or they will "bleed" outside the rounded corners.

Give this a try (only slightly modified). It's designated `@IBDesignable` so you can see how it looks in Storyboard / Interface Builder (I did not set any of the properties to inspectable -- I'll leave that up to you if you want to do so):

```
@IBDesignable
class MyRSButton: UIButton {

    var shouldApplyShadow: Bool = true
    var innerShadows: Bool?

    var cornerRadi: CGFloat = 8.0

    var shadowLayer: CAShapeLayer!
    var shadowRadius: CGFloat?
    var shadowColor: UIColor?
    var shadowOffset: CGSize?
    var shadowOpacity: Float?

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        applyShadow()
    }

    private func applyShadow() {

        // needed to prevent background color from bleeding past
        // the rounded corners
        cornerRadi = bounds.size.height * 0.5
        layer.cornerRadius = cornerRadi

        layer.masksToBounds = false

        if shouldApplyShadow && shadowLayer == nil {
            shadowLayer = CAShapeLayer()

            let shapePath = CGPath(roundedRect: bounds, cornerWidth: cornerRadi, cornerHeight: cornerRadi, transform: nil)

            shadowLayer.path = shapePath
            shadowLayer.fillColor = backgroundColor?.cgColor
            shadowLayer.shadowPath = shadowLayer.path
            shadowLayer.shadowRadius = shadowRadius ?? 8
            shadowLayer.shadowColor = (shadowColor ?? .black).cgColor
            shadowLayer.shadowOffset = shadowOffset ?? CGSize(width: 0, height: 0)
            shadowLayer.shadowOpacity = shadowOpacity ?? 0.8

            layer.insertSublayer(shadowLayer!, at: 0)

            /// If there's background color, there is no need to mask inner shadows.
            if backgroundColor != .none && !(innerShadows ?? false) {
                let maskLayer = CAShapeLayer()
                maskLayer.path = { () -> UIBezierPath in
                    let path = UIBezierPath()
                    path.append(UIBezierPath(cgPath: shapePath))

                    // define a rect that is 80-pts wider and taller
                    // than the button... this will "expand" it from center
                    let r = bounds.insetBy(dx: -40, dy: -40)

                    path.append(UIBezierPath(rect: r))

                    path.usesEvenOddFillRule = true
                    return path
                    }().cgPath

                maskLayer.fillRule = .evenOdd
                shadowLayer.mask = maskLayer
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks @DonMag ! That's actually a little workaround but it solves my problem %99 of the time.